# Magento2 The product's required option(s) weren't entered. Make sure the options are entered and try again

Tags: magento2

```
$product = $this->productFactory->create()->load($productId);

        $params = [
    'form_Key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
    'product' => $productId,
    'qty' => '1',
    'options' => [
        '2' => '3',
    ],
];

        $this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);
        $this->cart->save();
```

I am using above code to pass Customizable options data to cart, but getting error

> The product's required option(s) weren't entered. Make sure the
> options are entered and try again.